# Models give different scores when predictions are made in a loop VS when predictions are made from a list of models

Tags: python, scikit-learn, decision-tree

The variable `grid.best_estimator_` contains a Decision Tree model found from GridSearchCV

```
for subset in range(len(smol_X_train)):
    temp_tree = grid.best_estimator_.fit(smol_X_train[subset], smol_y_train[subset])
    pred = temp_tree.predict(X_test)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, pred)
    print(accuracy)
```

Output-

```
0.827
0.7025 
0.782 
0.7205 
..
..
0.8365
0.8395
```

With a list-

```
tree_list = []

for subset in range(len(smol_X_train)):
    temp_tree = grid.best_estimator_.fit(smol_X_train[subset], smol_y_train[subset])
    tree_list.append(temp_tree)

for one_tree in tree_list:
    pred = one_tree.predict(X_test)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, pred)
    print(accuracy)
```

Output-

```
0.8395
0.8395
0.8395
0.8395
..
..
0.8395
0.8395
```

---

The models in the list are returning the same score (the score of the last model).

1. Why do the outputs differ here? Aren't the models stored in the list all fitted on different subsets and hence, should give different predictions too?
2. Is the *fitness* of the models (except the last one) lost when they're put in the list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloning, fitting the model and then appending it to a list did the trick. Rather than directly appending the model to the list.

```
from sklearn.base import clone

tree_list = []

for subset in range(len(smol_X_train)):
    temp_tree = grid.best_estimator_.fit(smol_X_train[subset], smol_y_train[subset])
    tree_list.append(clone(temp_tree))
    pred = temp_tree.predict(X_test)
    accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, pred)
    print(accuracy)
```